# How to open (as a list) a file containing a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, file

I have a one line text file, `file.txt` which contents are:

> ["word 1","word 2","word 3","word 4"]

I want to open this file so that Python reads it as a list.

When I use:

> line = (literal_eval(s) for s in open("file.txt"))
>
> print(len(line))

I notice that `line` variable is a list with just one item, as that prints out `1`

How do I open `file.,txt` to get a list with 4 items ("word 1", "word 2", "word 3", "word 4")?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of `json`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use (if you're sure the structure is as you mentioned it) :

```
line = '["word 1","word 2","word 3"]'
arr = line[1:-1].replace('"','').split(',')
print(arr) # => ['word 1', 'word 2', 'word 3'] as an array
```

A better, safe and easy way :

```
import json
line = '["word 1","word 2","word 3"]'
arr = json.loads(line)
print(arr) # => ['word 1', 'word 2', 'word 3'] as an array
```

To read the file's first line use :

```
import json
line = open('file.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()[0] # split lines and get the first one
arr = json.loads(line)
print(arr) # => ['word 1', 'word 2', 'word 3', 'word 4']
```

Comment: I get a `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable` error when I set `line` to the contents of `file.txt`

Comment: @user3672036 I explain in the edited answer.